# C++ regex split after first whitespace

Tags: c++, regex

I have a string as follows:

```
{ <object> waves   ;              big    yellow       flowers ;          slugs       ; }
```

And I need to come up with a correct regex to split it after the first white space, then after that only by the semicolons so that in a vector, it would look as follows:

```
s.at(0) = <object>
s.at(1) = waves
s.at(2) = big yellow flowers
s.at(3) = slugs
```

The closest I've come to is just splitting it by the semicolons, but `<object>` and waves end up being read as one line.

Edit: This is the split function I'm using

```
vector<string> split(const string &input, const string &regex, bool delim = true) {
std::regex re(regex);

std::sregex_token_iterator first, last;
if (delim) {
    first = sregex_token_iterator{input.begin(), input.end(), re};
} else {
    // the -1 removes the delimiter
    first = sregex_token_iterator{input.begin(), input.end(), re, -1};
}
return vector<string>(first, last);
}
```

Comment: Do the elements in between `; ` always start with a letter/word char?

Comment: Are the number of semicolons fixed?

Comment: Elements in between ; always start with either a letter or a digit, and the number of semicolons are not fixed. Some other strings I'm handling have more separators

Comment: You can't do this with one regex if the number of captures is unknown. Or at least you would have to us a regex iterator rather than capture groups.

Comment: Personally I would not use regex for this. It would be simple enough to use string manipulation.

Comment: You changed the input string considerably. Now, you want to remove excessive whitespace before actually splitting, right?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Since you updated the input you have, the suggestion below will work after some preprocessing: you need to remove excessive whitespace and the leading/trailing braces.

```
std::regex r(R"(^[{\s]+|[}\s]+$|\s*(;)\s*|(\s)+)");
```

And replace with `"$1$2"`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0NgjmI/1).

You can only achieve that with *matching*, not splitting. The regex is

```
^\S+|\b[^;]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GgQDXl/1)

It matches:

- `^\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars at the start of a string
- `|` - or 
  -`\b[^;]+` - word boundary followed with 1+ chars other than `;`. It should work since the elements start with digit/letter (as per your comments).

Sample C++ code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex r(R"(^\S+|\b\w[^;]*)");
    std::string s = "<start> sunlight; small red flowers; trees;";
    for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
      i != std::sregex_iterator();
      ++i)
    {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        std::cout << m.str() <<  '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/UdVYGy)

Comment: You can avoid creating an `std::smatch` by dereferencing the iterator: `i->str()` (it's already an std::smatch).

Comment: It isn't working with mine. It may be the split function that I'm using -- I updated my question to include it.

Comment: [Works OK for me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4f2ff91be26caad)

Comment: I said use *matching* rather than *splitting*, and push matches into the string vector. See https://ideone.com/VpelBH

Comment: @AlyssaJune No, it does not work (well) on your new example.  Your original had neither brackets nor excessive whitespace, so I wouldn't expect a regex designed to handle the original example to work with your new example.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, sorry I edited the string considerably. After re-looking at my code, I didn't notice the curly braces before. Your code works -- however is there a way to keep "big yellow flowers" on the same line?

Comment: I do not understand you: what *line*? Please see https://ideone.com/gXpcaj, feel free to modify to show the issue

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood. I think it's only not working for me because of the way my split function is structured. The split function I'm required to use is posted in my question.

Comment: @AlyssaJune: You cannot use *splitting* here, I stated it in my answer. You *have* to change it or you will never get the results. Why? Because you need to check the context of the non-word char you are splitting on, and you must  check if the space is coming after the first word that is inside `<` and `>`. As ECMAScript does not support lookbehinds, you cannot use splitting here.